# Pinch zoom in Phonegap apk with html content

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap

I've created an html content that works fine in my Android browser. I use that HTML code to make an apk in phonegap but the pinch zoom does`t work. I've tried some tips found here as paste this in the index.html file:

But it is still not working.

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the **index.html** file you need to set `<meta content="user-scalable=yes">`.
By default it is set to no.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  You need to edit the MainActivity.java file and add the following to the top of the file.

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
```

Add these three lines after the loadUrl(launchUrl) line

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```